# Missing artifacts from maven .m2 repository

Tags: maven, dependencies, pom.xml, artifacts

I'm trying to add dependencies to my project through pom file. But while building workspace it's showing error as missing more than 400 artifacts. Seems like maven is not downloading related jars to my .m2 folder.

I tried cleaning and updating projects several times but errors are still there.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What error is being displayed? A stacktrace would be useful

Answer (score 0):

check your connection to repository configured in pom or settings.xml..as below

```html
...
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>my-repo1</id>
      <name>your custom repo</name>
      <url>http://jarsm2.dyndns.dk</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>my-repo2</id>
      <name>your custom repo</name>
      <url>http://jarsm2.dyndns.dk</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
...
</project>
```

Use [this link](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html)

If your are using in restricted network, please check your private organization maven repository and also check authentication to the server proxy as given on the below link and snippet

```html
Proxies
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  ...
  <proxies>
    <proxy>
      <id>myproxy</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>proxy.somewhere.com</host>
      <port>8080</port>
      <username>proxyuser</username>
      <password>somepassword</password>
      <nonProxyHosts>*.google.com|ibiblio.org</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
  ...
</settings>
```

[link to set proxy in settings.xml](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html)